# Replace the first value of each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a `df` sorted by `EmpID` and `Date`. Now I need to update the `Reason` column of the first occurrence for each `EmpID` with the value 100.

Original:

| EmpID | Date | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | 0 |
| 123 | 01/02/2022 | 500 |
| 123 | 01/03/2022 | 0 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 0 |
| 124 | 01/02/2022 | 800 |
| 124 | 01/03/2022 | 0 |

Result:

| EmpID | Date | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | 100 |
| 123 | 01/02/2022 | 500 |
| 123 | 01/03/2022 | 0 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 100 |
| 124 | 01/02/2022 | 800 |
| 124 | 01/03/2022 | 0 |

I'm not getting close in any attempts. Would it be easier to update the min date of each `EmpID` and set `Reason` to 100?

I have tried the following but received an error.

```py
DF.loc[DF.groupby(['EmpID','Date'])['Reason'].head(1), 'Reason'] = '100'
```

This raises:

> KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([  0.0, 800.0,   0.0, 800.0,   0.0, 800.0,   0.0, 800.0,   0.0,\n              800.0,\n              ...\n              800.0,   0.0, 100.0, 800.0,   0.0, 100.0, 800.0,   0.0, 100.0,\n              800.0],\n             dtype='float64', name='EEID', length=12769)] are in the [index]"

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `duplicated`

```
df.loc[~df['EmpID'].duplicated(),'Reason'] = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html). Just define a function that returns a mask: with all the values `False` except for the first one: `True`.

With the combined mask of all the groups you can then select and replace the elements that you need:

```py
def f(s):
    mask = np.full(len(s), False)
    mask[0] = True
    return mask

mask = df.groupby('EmpID')['Reason'].transform(f)
df.loc[mask, 'Reason'] = 100
```

Result:

```py
   EmpID       Date  Reason
0    123 2022-01-01     100
1    123 2022-01-02     500
2    123 2022-01-03       0
3    124 2022-01-01     100
4    124 2022-01-02     800
5    124 2022-01-03       0
```

Answer (score 0):

for solving this problem we need to identify the row number if we get the row number we can filter based on 1st row and change the reason to 100. we can get row number using this function [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
data['row_num'] =data.groupby(['EmpID']).cumcount()
data.loc[data.row_num == 0,'Reason'] = 100
data
```

[image]